# How can I get the context outside of the build in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, flutter-packages, flutter-gridview

I use StreamProvider to receive firestore data in my app. And I use [lazy_load_scrollview](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview/example) package for the pagination in the image gridview. In the StreamProvider I have to pass context to listen to data streams. Just like  Provider.of<List>(context) . So I have to define it inside the build. But in the _loadMore() method I have defined in the code I need images(this is where I listen to the Stream) list to update the data list for pagination. Pagination works fine but when I first launch the app it only shows the loading indicator and does not load anything. When I swipe down the screen it starts loading and pagination works fine. To load the grid items when I first start, I need to call _loadMore() method in the initState(). I can't call it because it is inside the build. But I can't define that method outside of the build because it needs to define Stream listener(which is images). I can't get the context outside from the build to do that. Is there any way to get the context outside of the build ? or is there any better solution for pagination ? I would be grateful if you can suggest me a solution. here is my code,

```
class ImageGridView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageGridViewState createState() => _ImageGridViewState();
}

class _ImageGridViewState extends State<ImageGridView> {

  List<GridImage> data = [];
  int currentLength = 0;

  final int increment = 10;
  bool isLoading = false;

  // I need to call _loadMore() method inside the initState
  /*@override
  void initState() {
   _loadMore();
    super.initState();
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // listening to firebase streams
    final images = Provider.of<List<GridImage>>(context) ?? [];
    

    Future _loadMore() async {
      print('_loadMore called');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      // Add in an artificial delay
      await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      for (var i = currentLength; i < currentLength + increment; i++) {

      if (i >= images.length) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        print( i.toString());
      } else {
        data.add(images[i]);
      }

    }

    setState(() {
      print('future delayed called');
      isLoading = false;
      currentLength = data.length;
    });
  } 

    images.forEach((data) {
      print('data' + data.location);
      print(data.url);
      //print('images length ' + images.length.toString());
    }); 

    try {

      return LazyLoadScrollView(
        isLoading: isLoading,
        onEndOfPage: () {
          return _loadMore();
        },
          child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length + 1,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {

            if (index == data.length) {
              return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
            } 
            
            //passing images stream with the item index to ImageGridItem
            return ImageGridItem(gridImage: data[index],); 
          },

        ),
      );
      
    } catch (e) {

      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Please Upload Images'),
        )
      );

    }

    
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even have that method inside the build method!! Move it outside the build method 

Comment: @OMiShah yes we can easily pass the context to a method outside of the build with a parameter.But the problem is It gives an error when I call it inside the initState. The reason is initState doesn't have the actual context to use for the StreamBuilder. I've been struggling with this few days and now I found a solution for that. We can call _loadMore inside didChangeDependencies method which is called after initState and before build. I just found this way to solve the issue. Do you have any suggetion on that? btw thanks for the reply

Comment: You have actually messed up so much for such a little thing!!

Comment: @OMiShah yaya  I always messed up little things than complicated ones. My bad. I'm new to flutter and learning it further. Anyway Thanks again for replying. Really appreciate it